# QueryException : SQLSTATE[42S02] Base table or view not found

Tags: sql, laravel, composer-php, database-migration

So I have an error while try to run laravel from my github repo. It says SQLSTATE[42502], I try to solve by looking the same topic, but still, comeback stuck.

**The chronological order is simple like this**

1. I pull a repository from github
2. I run composer update and all package in vendors folder started to install one by one
3. Until it try to generate best auto-load and the error appears

BTW I only have the database migration file and not the .SQL one.

So if anyone of you could help, I really appreciate it. Thanks

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'laravel.product_requests' doesn't exist (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `product_requests` where `read_at` is null)

  at C:\xampp\htdocs\ayoreview-master\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:669
    665|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    666|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    667|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    668|         catch (Exception $e) {
  > 669|             throw new QueryException(
    670|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    671|             );
    672|         }
    673|

  Exception trace:

  1   Illuminate\Foundation\Application::Illuminate\Foundation\{closure}(Object(App\Providers\AppServiceProvider))
      [internal]:0

  2   Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException::("SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'laravel.product_requests' doesn't exist")
      C:\xampp\htdocs\ayoreview-master\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOConnection.php:66
```

My related migration file for **product_requests**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateProductRequestsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('product_requests', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->text('specification');
            $table->bigInteger('price');
            $table->string('link');
            $table->string('featured_image');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('category_id')->nullable();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('brand_id')->nullable();
            $table->text('description')->nullable();
            $table->dateTime('read_at')->nullable();
            $table->dateTime('exported_at')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('product_requests');
    }
}
```

**More Detail**

AppServiceProvider

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use App\ProductRequest;
use Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        if(Config::get('app.redirect_https')) {
            URL::forceScheme('https');
        }
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        if(Config::get('app.redirect_https')) {
            $this->app['request']->server->set('HTTPS', true);
        }

        Paginator::defaultView('custom.pagination');

        $unreadRequestedProduct = ProductRequest::whereNull('read_at')->count();
        session()->flash('product_request', $unreadRequestedProduct);
    }
}
```

Full trace when doing composer update

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\ayoreview-master>composer update
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Package operations: 0 installs, 1 update, 0 removals
  - Updating laravel/framework (v6.18.31 => v6.18.32): Downloading (100%)
Package guzzle/guzzle is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use guzzlehttp/guzzle instead.
Package jakub-onderka/php-console-color is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use php-parallel-lint/php-console-color instead.
Package jakub-onderka/php-console-highlighter is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use php-parallel-lint/php-console-highlighter instead.
Writing lock file
Generating optimized autoload files
Deprecation Notice: Class Guzzle\Tests\Common\Cache\NullCacheAdapterTest located in C:/xampp/htdocs/ayoreview-master/vendor/guzzle/guzzle/tests\Guzzle\Tests\Cache\NullCacheAdapterTest.php does not comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. It will not autoload anymore in Composer v2.0. in phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Autoload/ClassMapGenerator.php:201
Deprecation Notice: Class Guzzle\Tests\Common\AbstractHasAdapterTest located in C:/xampp/htdocs/ayoreview-master/vendor/guzzle/guzzle/tests\Guzzle\Tests\Common\AbstractHasDispatcherTest.php does not comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. It will not autoload anymore in Composer v2.0. in phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Autoload/ClassMapGenerator.php:201
Deprecation Notice: Class Guzzle\Tests\Message\HeaderComparisonTest located in C:/xampp/htdocs/ayoreview-master/vendor/guzzle/guzzle/tests\Guzzle\Tests\Http\Message\HeaderComparisonTest.php does not comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. It will not autoload anymore in Composer v2.0. in phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Autoload/ClassMapGenerator.php:201
Deprecation Notice: Class Guzzle\Tests\Http\Message\HttpRequestFactoryTest located in C:/xampp/htdocs/ayoreview-master/vendor/guzzle/guzzle/tests\Guzzle\Tests\Http\Message\RequestFactoryTest.php does not comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. It will not autoload anymore in Composer v2.0. in phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Autoload/ClassMapGenerator.php:201
Deprecation Notice: Class Guzzle\Tests\Message\ResponseTest located in C:/xampp/htdocs/ayoreview-master/vendor/guzzle/guzzle/tests\Guzzle\Tests\Http\Message\ResponseTest.php does not comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. It will not autoload anymore in Composer v2.0. in phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Autoload/ClassMapGenerator.php:201
Deprecation Notice: Class Guzzle\Tests\Http\CommaAggregatorTest located in C:/xampp/htdocs/ayoreview-master/vendor/guzzle/guzzle/tests\Guzzle\Tests\Http\QueryAggregator\CommaAggregatorTest.php does not comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. It will not autoload anymore in Composer v2.0. in phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Autoload/ClassMapGenerator.php:201
Deprecation Notice: Class Guzzle\Tests\Http\DuplicateAggregatorTest located in C:/xampp/htdocs/ayoreview-master/vendor/guzzle/guzzle/tests\Guzzle\Tests\Http\QueryAggregator\DuplicateAggregatorTest.php does not comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. It will not autoload anymore in Composer v2.0. in phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Autoload/ClassMapGenerator.php:201
Deprecation Notice: Class Guzzle\Tests\Http\PhpAggregatorTest located in C:/xampp/htdocs/ayoreview-master/vendor/guzzle/guzzle/tests\Guzzle\Tests\Http\QueryAggregator\PhpAggregatorTest.php
does not comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. It will not autoload anymore in Composer v2.0. in phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Autoload/ClassMapGenerator.php:201
Deprecation Notice: Class Guzzle\Tests\Plugin\Redirect\RedirectPluginTest located in C:/xampp/htdocs/ayoreview-master/vendor/guzzle/guzzle/tests\Guzzle\Tests\Http\RedirectPluginTest.php does not comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. It will not autoload anymore in Composer v2.0. in phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Autoload/ClassMapGenerator.php:201
Deprecation Notice: Class Guzzle\Tests\Plugin\Redirect\StaticClientTest located in C:/xampp/htdocs/ayoreview-master/vendor/guzzle/guzzle/tests\Guzzle\Tests\Http\StaticClientTest.php does not comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. It will not autoload anymore in Composer v2.0. in phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Autoload/ClassMapGenerator.php:201
Deprecation Notice: Class Guzzle\Tests\Parsers\UriTemplate\AbstractUriTemplateTest located in C:/xampp/htdocs/ayoreview-master/vendor/guzzle/guzzle/tests\Guzzle\Tests\Parser\UriTemplate\AbstractUriTemplateTest.php does not comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. It will not autoload anymore in Composer v2.0. in phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Autoload/ClassMapGenerator.php:201
Deprecation Notice: Class Guzzle\Tests\Parsers\UriTemplate\PeclUriTemplateTest located in C:/xampp/htdocs/ayoreview-master/vendor/guzzle/guzzle/tests\Guzzle\Tests\Parser\UriTemplate\PeclUriTemplateTest.php does not comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. It will not autoload anymore in Composer v2.0. in phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Autoload/ClassMapGenerator.php:201
Deprecation Notice: Class Guzzle\Tests\Parsers\UriTemplate\UriTemplateTest located in C:/xampp/htdocs/ayoreview-master/vendor/guzzle/guzzle/tests\Guzzle\Tests\Parser\UriTemplate\UriTemplateTest.php does not comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. It will not autoload anymore in Composer v2.0. in phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Autoload/ClassMapGenerator.php:201
Deprecation Notice: Class Guzzle\Tests\Service\ServiceBuilderTest located in C:/xampp/htdocs/ayoreview-master/vendor/guzzle/guzzle/tests\Guzzle\Tests\Service\Builder\ServiceBuilderTest.php
does not comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. It will not autoload anymore in Composer v2.0. in phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Autoload/ClassMapGenerator.php:201
Deprecation Notice: Class Guzzle\Tests\Service\Command\AliasFactoryTest located in C:/xampp/htdocs/ayoreview-master/vendor/guzzle/guzzle/tests\Guzzle\Tests\Service\Command\Factory\AliasFactoryTest.php does not comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. It will not autoload anymore in Composer v2.0. in phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Autoload/ClassMapGenerator.php:201
Deprecation Notice: Class Guzzle\Tests\Service\Command\CompositeFactoryTest located in C:/xampp/htdocs/ayoreview-master/vendor/guzzle/guzzle/tests\Guzzle\Tests\Service\Command\Factory\CompositeFactoryTest.php does not comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. It will not autoload anymore in Composer v2.0. in phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Autoload/ClassMapGenerator.php:201
Deprecation Notice: Class Guzzle\Tests\Service\Command\ConcreteClassFactoryTest located in C:/xampp/htdocs/ayoreview-master/vendor/guzzle/guzzle/tests\Guzzle\Tests\Service\Command\Factory\ConcreteClassFactoryTest.php does not comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. It will not autoload anymore in Composer v2.0. in phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Autoload/ClassMapGenerator.php:201
Deprecation Notice: Class Guzzle\Tests\Service\Command\MapFactoryTest located in C:/xampp/htdocs/ayoreview-master/vendor/guzzle/guzzle/tests\Guzzle\Tests\Service\Command\Factory\MapFactoryTest.php does not comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. It will not autoload anymore in Composer v2.0. in phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Autoload/ClassMapGenerator.php:201
Deprecation Notice: Class Guzzle\Tests\Service\Command\ServiceDescriptionFactoryTest located in C:/xampp/htdocs/ayoreview-master/vendor/guzzle/guzzle/tests\Guzzle\Tests\Service\Command\Factory\ServiceDescriptionFactoryTest.php does not comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. It will not autoload anymore in Composer v2.0. in phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Autoload/ClassMapGenerator.php:201
Deprecation Notice: Class Guzzle\Tests\Service\Command\VisitorFlyweightTest located in C:/xampp/htdocs/ayoreview-master/vendor/guzzle/guzzle/tests\Guzzle\Tests\Service\Command\LocationVisitor\VisitorFlyweightTest.php does not comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. It will not autoload anymore in Composer v2.0. in phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Autoload/ClassMapGenerator.php:201
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
> @php artisan package:discover --ansi

   Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'laravel.product_requests' doesn't exist (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `product_requests` where `read_at` is null)

  at C:\xampp\htdocs\ayoreview-master\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:669
    665|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    666|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    667|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    668|         catch (Exception $e) {
  > 669|             throw new QueryException(
    670|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    671|             );
    672|         }
    673|

  Exception trace:

  1   Illuminate\Foundation\Application::Illuminate\Foundation\{closure}(Object(App\Providers\AppServiceProvider))
      [internal]:0

  2   Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException::("SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'laravel.product_requests' doesn't exist")
      C:\xampp\htdocs\ayoreview-master\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOConnection.php:66

  Please use the argument -v to see more details.
Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1
```

Composer.json

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "laravel"
    ],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.2",
        "ext-gd": "*",
        "ext-imagick": "*",
        "doctrine/dbal": "^2.10",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
        "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.0",
        "intervention/image": "^2.5",
        "laravel/framework": "^6.2",
        "laravel/sanctum": "^2.3",
        "laravel/socialite": "^4.4",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.0",
        "league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3": "~1.0",
        "santigarcor/laratrust": "^6.0",
        "yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle": "~9.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "barryvdh/laravel-debugbar": "^3.3",
        "barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper": "^2.7",
        "facade/ignition": "^1.4",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "laravel/ui": "^1.0",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.0",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^3.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^8.0",
        "spatie/laravel-web-tinker": "^1.7"
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        },
        "files": [
            "app/Helpers/helper.php"
        ],
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate",
            "@php artisan ide-helper:generate"
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: `Base table or view not found:` means your database does not have the `table` or `view` / table in this case. Have you run the migration?

Comment: @user3532758 So everytime i want to run $php artisan xxx the error is come out, So even I can not run the $php migrate function.

This is occurred when I try to do the composer update

Comment: do composer dump, then artisan migrate

Comment: @wschopohl ee same result mate, the error come out when running composer dump-autoload command

Comment: Please share more details - to me this looks like you are already using the given model in the constructor of any service or somewhere else on bootstrapping your application. Obviously, this fails when the table does not exist, and running a migration is not possible as long as the bootstrapping fails

Comment: @NicoHaase what other detail should I upload mate? I would love to give it

Comment: I agree, is there a full stack trace, that shows more info?

Comment: And what's inside AppServiceProvider ?

Comment: I added several detail

Comment: ....well: your class performs some action on booting, like I've assumed: what do you think how `$unreadRequestedProduct` should get populated if the migration has not run yet?

Comment: Any instruction on how to overcome this problem mate?

Comment: Remove that line, run the migration, add that line again

Comment: When you get this error? On migration or when you visit on a page?

Comment: @STA I simply just start a composer update to installing the vendor folder and that error pop up

Comment: On `AppServiceProvider` delete everything from `boot` function, then try to update again. And let here know the update

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys, I think I solved this with trying to forced the migration first then do the composer update later. You guys were right it caused maybe by the error from something on boot so it postponed the migration process. So I just create a new fresh laravel folder and doing the migration freshly there.

**Here my step by step**

```
1. create new laravel folder
2. copy & paste database folder from the original repo
3. do migrate
    - if " Error
  Class 'Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOMySql\Driver' not found
    - do composer require doctrine/dbal
4. continue migrate again   
5. copy & paste all the rest of folder & file from the original repo
6. composer install
```

**DONE**

Thanks for all of your comment